# how does the break statement works in the below code

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
class Solution {
  public int heightChecker(int[] arr) {
    int count=0;
    int n=arr.length;
    int[] arr1=new int[101];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
      arr1[arr[i]]++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
      for(int j=1;j<101;j++) {
        if(arr1[j]!=0) {
          if(arr[i]!=j) {
            count++;
          }
          arr1[j]--;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

`break;`, on its own (vs a labelled break that looks like `break someName;` and is quite a bit different) will break the **nearest** breakable entity. `for`, `do`, `while`, and `switch` are directly breakable (and any braces are breakable using labelled breaks, but this isn't a labelled break).

The nearest for loop (as in, look at the brace pairs that the `break` is in; find the one that you hit soonest that goes with a breakable entity) is the `for (int j` loop (not the `if (arr[i] != j)` one - `if` is not label-less breakable). The `break` will break that loop.

Meaning, the code will jump immediately out of where-ever it is, skipping past everything needed so that we end up right *after* that for loop.

So, that `break` statement will jump out of the `for (int j=` block entirely, and will then execute the next thing. Which is `}` - the closing brace that goes with the `for (int i = 0` statement, so that for loop 'loops': `i` is incremented (as the increment part of that loops is `i++`, then `i < n` is executed. If its true, we jump back to the top of the outer for loop. If it is false, we fall through, and run the next line (which would be `return count;`).